# identity session timeout when multiple iis application pool processes used

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

In my asp.net mvc 5 application Idenity authentication is expiring quickly when multiple iis processes used for application pool.

If i change the no of iis application pool processes to 1, authentication works as usual.

Please advice what is the reason for the above issue and what can be done to use multiple processes in iis app pool without losing session. I have good amount of server resource hence want to make most of them.

Comment: Are you sure this is Identity? Identity does not use session for anything.

Comment: yes, very sure :). I have written session to indicate the user session only